# Getting the complete command line that caused an ERR , while trap

Tags: shell-script, ksh, error-handling, trap

How do I make trap to return the command that caused an ERR?

```
$function err_handler() { echo "$0 caused the error"; }

$ trap err_handler ERR

$ grep -ci "failed" test4 &>/dev/null
-bash caused the error
```

I wanted the output like

```
grep caused the error
```

and possibly ( greedy enough ) to have the entire substituted command line. Is it possible ( without any hacks )?

EDIT: I apologize for not mentioning that my shell is KSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the command history is enabled (off by default for non-interactive shells) and use that:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o history
function trapper () {
    printf "culprit: "
    history 1
}

trap trapper ERR

# your errors go here
```

Comment: This works perfectly for bash, but I am using ksh. I tried the above idea with ksh , replacing history 1 with fc -nl -1 inside my ksh script, but it said  "fc: history functions not available"
, which I ll post as a separate questions.But, this answer is right.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Bash, you can use the `$BASH_COMMAND` parameter:

```
BASH_COMMAND
    The command currently being executed or about to be executed, unless
    the shell is executing a command as the result of a trap, in which case
    it is the command executing at the time of the trap.
```

A few notes: One, `$BASH_COMMAND` gives you just the command that failed in compound commands, not the entire command line.

```
$ function err_handler { echo "error: $BASH_COMMAND" }
$ trap err_handler ERR
$ true blah blah blah && false herp derp
error: false herp derp
```

Two, a pipeline only fails if the last command fails. It still succeeds if intermediate commands fail but the last command succeeds:

```
$ echo okay | false herp derp | true lol
# err_handler not called, the last command returned true.
```

Three, `$BASH_COMMAND` gives you the *unparsed* command line, so the first thing on the command line is not necessarily the name of the command in unusual circumstances:

```
$ false herp derp                       # This is okay.
error: false herp derp
$ {false,herp,derp}                     # An obfuscated way to write `false blah blah`
error: {false,herp,derp}
$ cmd=false
$ $cmd herp derp                        
error: $cmd herp derp
```

Comment: I am sorry that I should have mentioned the shell as ksh.$BASH_COMMAND works well for bash.